# Java error stacktrace accumulation

Tags: java, exception

I develop smpp client, when i receive InvalidResponseException time after time, my stacktrace increase:

```
org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 0000000f found
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.validateResponse(AbstractSession.java:162)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:203)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.sendBind(SMPPSession.java:143)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.connectAndBind(SMPPSession.java:86)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.newSession(Gateway.java:107)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.getSession(Gateway.java:81)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.access$300(Gateway.java:33)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway$SessionStateListenerImpl.onStateChange(Gateway.java:196)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.fireStateChanged(AbstractSessionContext.java:69)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.changeState(SMPPSessionContext.java:44)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.close(AbstractSessionContext.java:58)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.close(SMPPSessionContext.java:10)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.close(AbstractSession.java:141)
```

then stacktrace was increase:

```
org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 0000000f found
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.validateResponse(AbstractSession.java:162)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:203)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.sendBind(SMPPSession.java:143)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.connectAndBind(SMPPSession.java:86)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.newSession(Gateway.java:107)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.getSession(Gateway.java:81)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.access$300(Gateway.java:33)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway$SessionStateListenerImpl.onStateChange(Gateway.java:196)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.fireStateChanged(AbstractSessionContext.java:69)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.changeState(SMPPSessionContext.java:44)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.close(AbstractSessionContext.java:58)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.close(SMPPSessionContext.java:10)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.close(AbstractSession.java:141)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.connectAndBind(SMPPSession.java:100)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.newSession(Gateway.java:107)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.getSession(Gateway.java:81)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway.access$300(Gateway.java:33)
    at com.sms.client.gw.Gateway$SessionStateListenerImpl.onStateChange(Gateway.java:196)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.fireStateChanged(AbstractSessionContext.java:69)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.changeState(SMPPSessionContext.java:44)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSessionContext.close(AbstractSessionContext.java:58)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSessionContext.close(SMPPSessionContext.java:10)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.close(AbstractSession.java:141)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$EnquireLinkSender.run(SMPPSession.java:394)
```

and larger and larger. How it can be? Why stacktrace accumulate ?
Between the response I set SMPPSessionContext variable to null, and SMPPSession to null

Comment: I am not understanding your question.  Are you asking why the first stacktrace is shorter than the second stacktrace?  If so, it is either (1) because the first stacktrace likely originates at a call to close() and the second stacktrace originates at a call to run(), or (2) you are catching and logging the stack trace after the call to close() and rethrowing the exception and logging the stack trace after the call to run().

Comment: You seem to have a recursive loop in your code.

Comment: i`m call close, then set SMPPSessionContext to null and SMPPSession to null, then created new session and context but trace large

Comment: in sessioncontext created and not closed executorService. Can be this a reason this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is a listener to the `close session` event that tries to open a new session. At the same time, the `connectAndBind` method, when detecting failure, tries to close the session, triggering yet another recursive cycle. So stop doing that, stop trying to open a session inside the `close` event callback (that's your class `Gateway$SessionStateListenerImpl`).